# React Native iOS "Show Inspector" pushed to the bottom of screen

Tags: ios, react-native

The "Show Inspector" hud overlay is pushed to the bottom of the screen (see image), how can I open it correct?

I've tried clicking on the tabs and dragging it back up but nothing happens other than the highlighting of the selected tab.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same question a few mins ago.

Basically that happens when you have a debugging tool open like Flipper or React Native Debugger opens.

So what you see it is just a minor tab.

But take a look at your debugging tool should look like this:

[image: React Developer Tools]

If you wanna deep dive into that just check this link: https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging#integration-with-react-native-inspector